# How to convert a PDF document to PNG?

Tags: pdf, conversion, png, printing

Is there a free way to convert a PDF document to a PNG image?

Comment: I asked a similar question last year on Stack Overflow. You can [read the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955238/snapshot-image-from-pdf-document) there.

Comment: Related: [How to convert a multi-page PDF file to PNG files, with one PNG file per page of the PDF document? (Windows)](http://superuser.com/q/243461/10259)

Comment: Open in Photoshop and save as PNG

Comment: @Raymond (OP): I know you didn't ask for a command line version, but using imagemagick is more versatile and is objectively the more useful answer. I think you should accept that as the answer instead: https://superuser.com/a/185897/5761

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This is overkill for what you need, but in the absence of another answer, [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) can do this for you.  Just install it, open the PDF, and save-as a PNG.

Comment: No more overkill than the 5 or so 'free' programs I installed that left a watermark on the image. Worked beautifully, thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I wanted to convert a PDF to a high-resolution PNG file, and using GIMP worked really great!

Comment: Thanks, have tried several tools, either with watermarks or other limitations. GIMP works fine.

Comment: Gimp works great for a single page, but I don't see a simple way to export lots of pages automatically. I'm sure if you know gimp well you could use automation tools to get it working. But perhaps pdftoppm is better.

Comment: @chrishiestand, You should post that as an alternative answer.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, but I don't think it is sufficient to stand alone. It's really just an addendum to your answer.

Comment: Route is "import" -> export as

Comment: While this is an old post, I think it may be worth pointing out that GIMP is not an ideal solution - at least I remember it not readin a pdf file generated by R correctly. Using pfftoppm with R generated pdf plots produces the correct image. (And Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro works too if you have it - can't speak about other versions.)

Comment: Just don't make the mistake of trying to actually edit the PNG with GIMP if you know how to use any other image editor. Convert and export.

Comment: For multi page pdfs you can File>Open_as_layers then File>Export_Layers using the [export layers as png plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/28268)

Comment: An update may be in order. With the 2.8.16 version of GIMP, I found that "Export as" is used instead of "Save as".

Comment: Not a bad answer. I had to deal with a very large detailed PDF and I found Sketch totally locked up on me. Memory limitation could exist for GIMP as well? Went with the command line answer.

Answer (score 174):

Personally I prefer the results obtained from pdftoppm from [Poppler utilities](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/):

`pdftoppm -png myfile.pdf > myfile.png`

If you have [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed, you can just type:

`convert myfile.pdf myfile.png`

*Note:* To use ImageMagick, you may also need Ghostscript.

*Note:* On Windows, `convert` is a system program, so you'd need to run the ImageMagick `convert` binary by using it's full path.

---

To install Poppler from the command line (provides the `pdftoppm` command)...

On Windows, you can use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/):

`choco install poppler`

On Mac, you can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

`brew install poppler`

Comment: on mac with homebrew I had to install imagemagick and ghostscript for this to work.

brew install imagemagick
brew install ghostscript

Comment: +1 for `pdftoppm`: good results and fast.

Comment: Why do you prefer the results of pdftoppm? I notice that the default output resolution is higher than imagemagick (although this can be changed), but apart from that they seem comparable on my test file.

Comment: Poppler does a much better job for me - I've got an input pdf with CYMK colours, with imagemagick the colours come out a crazy bright cyan. Also convert takes ~8 seconds and pdftoppm takes less than 0.5 seconds. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: converting multipage PDF with poppler will look more like this: `pdftoppm -png myfile.pdf myfile`

Comment: Informally comparing them head to head, I found pdftoppm about 5x (for PNG) to 16x (for JPG) faster once I adjusted for the same resolution.  My test file was a scientific paper 10 pages long.

Comment: See http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/ for windows binaries of poppler and use `pdftocairo -png`

Comment: Note that if you use imagemagick, you may also need ghostscript: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32466112/1157054

Comment: `attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' `

Comment: @Vimos Might be a bug in your version of ghostscript or imagemagick, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion).

Answer (score 19):

**Windows:** Install [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) and open your PDF. Print it to the PDFCreator printer (or whatever you called it) and hit save. When you hit save, after choosing a filename, set the filetype to PNG.

**Linux**: Install ImageMagick (on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`) and then in a terminal type: `convert [Input PDF File.pdf] [Output PNG File.png]`.

**Mac OS X:** Open the PDF in Preview and in the Save As dialog, set the filetype to png.

Comment: On macOS you can also use the build-in `sips` tool: `sips -s format png the_pdf_file.pdf --out the_png_file.png`

Answer (score 12):

You could also use `GS`:

```
"c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin64.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -dUseCropBox -sOutputFile="path_to_png_files\pdffilename-%03d.png" "path_to_pdf_file\pdffilename.pdf"
```

The path to `GS` should be adjusted based on your installation.

The `DEVICE` parameter here will specify grayscale. You can also output with color instead. These settings will allow you to output to 24-bit color, 300 dpi PNG files using the RGB.icc color profile:

```
-sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputICCProfile=default_rgb.icc -r300
```

Compared to `convert`, `GS` seems to run much faster, and it is more suitable for big batches of conversion.

Comment: Signed up for super user just to upvote this. Now if I only had any hope of remembering it...

Answer (score 9):

Another way is

```
inkscape -d 300 -e "$filename.png" "$filename.pdf"
```

with `-e` short for `--export-png` and `-d` short for `--export-dpi` (you can omit `-d 300` if you only need 96 dpi).

However, `inkscape` may have problems with the fonts, which is why I prefer `convert` from ImageMagick (see 
[frabjous'](https://superuser.com/a/185897/260809) and [digitxp's](https://superuser.com/a/185895/260809) answers).

Comment: +1 for inkscape.  Because you can edit the pages, rework the diagrams and save as svg or even as pdf etc...

Comment: I think `-e` should be `-o`, no?

Comment: No, `-e` is correct. It is short for `--export-png`. There is no `-o` according to the manpage. Thanks for pointing that out; I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Which OS do you use?

On a Mac, it's as simple as opening the PDF in the Preview app and saving it as a PNG.

On http://www.zamzar.com/, you can convert many file types for free also.

Answer (score 5):

If using Windows, I would use [Bullzip PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php), simply choose print and then select .PNG as the file type.

[image]

Comment: [Make sure to uncheck the option to install toolbars and edit browser home page and search settings when installing Bullzip PDF Printer.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5aBN0.png)

Answer (score 3):

The docupub online tool works quite well, you get an image per page: http://docupub.com/pdfconvert/

Answer (score 2):

if you don't don't feel like downloading anything just copy the picture and paste in paint then save as PNG and there you have it. no watermarks, not downloading files.. simple

Comment: Paint can open PDFs?

Comment: @DanielBeck He's saying to open in a PDF viewer, then copy and paste

Comment: @CanadianLuke what PDF viewer allows you to do that? The default one on Windows 10 and 11 definitely doesn't.

Comment: @gargoylebident Try taking a screenshot of random PDFs

Comment: @CanadianLuke and what would that achieve?

Comment: @gargoylebident I'm not the OP, and this answer is 10 years old... I'm not sure if the OP is still around, but I think you should ask them.

Comment: @CanadianLuke no, I'm asking you because you told me to take a screenshot, not OP. What would taking a screenshot of random PDFs achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This free online tool:

[convert.town/pdf-to-png](http://convert.town/pdf-to-png)

will convert a PDF file to a PNG image inside your browser.  You won't need to install anything.

If the PDF is multi-page, it will create a new image for each page.

Answer (score 1):

Use [VIPS](https://www.libvips.org/).

```
vips copy filename.pdf[page=33,dpi=400] filename.png
```

The parameters in square brackets are explained in the [docs](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-pdfload):

> - `page` : `gint`, load this page, numbered from zero
> - `n` : `gint`, load this many pages
> - `dpi` : `gdouble`, render at this DPI
> - `scale` : `gdouble`, scale render by this factor
> - `background` : VipsArrayDouble background colour
> - `password` : `gchararray` background colour