# How to convert a multi-page PDF file to PNG files, with one PNG file per page of the PDF document?

Tags: windows, pdf, png, image-conversion

How do I convert a multi-page PDF file to PNG files, and automatically save one PNG file per page of the PDF document (for Windows 7)?

I have tried virtual printers (CutePDF, Bullzip PDF Printer) and image editing software (Irfanview, Photoshop) to convert PDF files to PNG but I can't find a way to make them save one PNG file per page of a PDF document.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/)

> -sOutputFile=filename
>   This is a general option telling Ghostscript what to name the output. It can either be a single filename 'tiger.png' or a template 'figure-%03d.jpg' where the %03d is replaced by the page number.

You may find it convenient to use GhostView, the GUI front end.

Comment: I experimented on a couple of options for GhostView and came to this group of options to automatically convert the PDF to PNGs without user prompts: `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r96 -sOutputFile="C:\directory_Output\%03d.png" "C:\directory_Input\pdfname.pdf"` Am I doing it right? 
I also would like to know what DPI I should set it to (I set it to 96 in this case) to have the same resolution as the source PDF. (The PDF files I am converting contains scanned images of a book or magazine, and does not have OCR text/information.)

Comment: If the source DPI is 96 and the image is likely to be mostly viewed on screen, 96 is a good choice for the output DPI, since that is the default display-DPI for MS Windows (though a few will set their display-DPI to 120).

Answer (score 35):

Using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (you'll need [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) installed as well), the command:

```
convert -density 300 filename.pdf filename.png
```

will result in a series of files `filename-0.png`, `filename-1.png`, `filename-2.png`, one for each of the pages of the PDF. You'll want to play around with the density setting to get a resolution you like.

You may need to give the full path to convert.exe on Windows; I've only ever done this on Linux, but it should work for Windows too.

Comment: I've been trying the Ghostscript method in the other answer above, but would now like to try this method you suggested. I'd like to ask if the `-density 300` argument means that the DPI setting is 300, or does it mean another thing?

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=2fnn3hjfigngkq179b6kssthk7#density).

Comment: If you only want one page, follow the PDF file name with the page number in square brackets: `filename.pdf[0]` The page number is 0-based, so 0 is first page, 1 is second page, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12614851/215168

Comment: Just a note: ImageMagick's `convert` does use Ghostscript when rendering `.pdf`s, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705727/convert-pdf-to-jpg-using-imagemagick-without-ghostscript

Comment: for this to work `gs` has to call the ghostscript binary (I had `gs` aliased to `git status`)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PDF-XChange](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer). It can export any pages you want to the expected format. Not only PNGs but many other formats are supported too

[image: Export images dialog]

[image: Export menu]

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer not to install any software, you can use this online tool:

[convert.town/pdf-to-png](http://convert.town/pdf-to-png)

The conversion is done inside your browser.  It will produce one PNG file for each PDF page.

Comment: Works very well, alas the images are only 75 DPI, which is not enough for print output.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example with `GS` with the `CropBox` option:

```
"c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin64.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -dUseCropBox -sOutputFile="path_to_png_files\pdffilename-%03d.png" "path_to_pdf_file\pdffilename.pdf"
```

The path to `GS` should be adjusted based on your installation. Also, the `DEVICE` parameter could be changed to a color device if required. Compared to `convert`, `GS` seems to run much faster, and it is more suitable for big batches of conversion.

Comment: If I'm not cropping any part of the original PDF file or converted PNG images, do I still need to use 'CropBox'? If yes, how does it help with the conversion process?

Comment: The use of `-dUseCropBox` is not to perform any cropping. Instead, it forces that `GS` reads the `CropBox` info from the input PDF. This is necessary to have a robust conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Another software to do the conversion is [PDFCreator](https://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator). It'll create a new printer in your system so you can actually convert from **any formats to images**, not only PDF files

> - Convert your documents to PDF, JPG, PNG, TIF and more
> - Merge multiple documents to one file
> - Profiles make frequently used settings available with one click
> - Use automatic saving to have a fully automated PDF printer
> - We take care of the complexity and make converting PDFs simple for you

More importantly it's also [open-sourced](https://github.com/pdfforge/PDFCreator)

Just print the document, select the PDFCreator and choose the output as PNG (or TIFF, JPG, whatever...) and you're done

[image: PDFCreator screenshot]