# Best settings to convert massive pdf hiking maps to images using ghostscript/imagemagick

Tags: pdf, images, conversion, imagemagick, ghostscript

I did convert all of the [Te Araroa](http://www.teararoa.org.nz/) Hiking Maps from PDFs to JPEGs so far. The original maps are 16-64MB PDFs, which take forever to load on my Android Phone. I converted them using Ghostscript and Imagemagic to jpgs similar as seen [here](https://superuser.com/a/243712/234440) with the following settings:

`convert.exe -density 200 05_v32_Manawatu_63_69.pdf %03d.jpg`

This gives me jpgs up to 4MB, which look quite nice on my phone. I'm wondering if I could make them smaller. I tried pngs, but somehow all the white borders around the maps are black on my maps.

I'm no image expert. Are there other image formats that would be suitable, like a reduced color gif?
If you want to give it a try, the smallest set of Te Araroa maps are the Manawatu maps with 16MB, which can be found [here](http://www.teararoa.org.nz/userfiles/file/regional_info/v32_Manawatu_63_69.pdf).

Comment: maybe webm (google's own format)

Comment: You can reduce the JPG quality by using the `-quality` option with a value from 1–100, where 1 is the lowest. The default would be 92, so there's a lot to improve in terms of file size. You can also try using GIFs with a reduced color palette of, say, 8 colors and dithering to smooth out color transitions. But that'll just reduce the readability and meaning of the colors on the map, which may not be suitable for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with reduction of quality to 80 and dpi reduced to 200:
`-density 200 -quality 80`
Worked out very well. You can find my convert scripts on [GitHub](https://github.com/funkybaboon/ta-scripts)